# Decryption of AES epub files to be parsed by EpubReader

Tags: android, encryption

How can I decrypt aes files using Android using the example below?

My aim is to store a set of AES encrypted ebooks in epub format in the assets folder of the Android app and decrypt them when required and display them in a webviewer using the nl.siegmann.epublib classes.

I encrypted the epub file using AES Crypt (https://www.aescrypt.com) using same 16 character code as in Java source. Once it compiles it takes a while but the asset file seems to decrypt, is stored in a local temp file, and is then parsed using epublib. Nothing shows up, however. I also noticed file length is different but I'm not sure if I'm reading that right.

I'm quite new to Android development and am using Android Studio 3.1.2

Btw, the reason for the encryption is files must be stored locally and publishers want a way to (try and) block copying of their epub books. Encrypting key will be hidden better when working. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.ebook;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String KEY = "1234567890123456";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        decryptFile();
    }

    public void decryptFile(){
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        try {
            String filename = "AccordingToLuke_9781874584292.epub.aes";
            String filePath = "ebooks/";

            // Get encrypted file from /assets
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(filePath + filename);
            Integer fileLength = inputStream.toString().length();

            // Create temp file to hold decrypted byte array
            File tmp = File.createTempFile("tmp", "decrypted", getCacheDir());
            tmp.deleteOnExit();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmp);

            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(),"AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);

            int b;
            byte[] d = new byte[8];
            while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
                fos.write(d, 0, b);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            cis.close();

            // Load book from tmp stream
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(tmp);
            Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(fileInputStream);
            Integer fileDecryptedLength = fileInputStream.toString().length();

            // Display decrypted epub file
            String contents = "";
            String authors = book.getMetadata().getAuthors().toString();
            contents = authors;
            webView.loadData(contents,"text/html","utf-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            webView.loadData("Problem loading ebook","text/html","utf-8");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please state your question in the form of a question w/ a question mark?

Comment: Sorry. How can I decrypt aes files using Android using the example above?

Comment: now put that into your actual question, not the comments section.
Thank you!

Comment: Stupid me! Hope that's ok now

Comment: I figured a work around by using encrypted zip files which I extracted into internal storage and decrypted them there